# Why response code is set firstly in method *Context.Render(code int, r render.Render) of gin?

Tags: go, go-gin

Gin has encapsulated some methods for constructing response, such as methods `*Context.JSON(code int, obj interface{})` and `*Context.String(code int, format string, values ...interface{})`. These methods all call the method `*Context.Render(code int, r render.Render)`.

```
// Render writes the response headers and calls render.Render to render data.
func (c *Context) Render(code int, r render.Render) {
    c.Status(code)

    if !bodyAllowedForStatus(code) {
        r.WriteContentType(c.Writer)
        c.Writer.WriteHeaderNow()
        return
    }

    if err := r.Render(c.Writer); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I wonder why the `Render` method call the method `Status` which will set the HTTP response code by calling the method `ResponseWriter.WriterHeader(statusCode int)` firstly.

`r.Render(c.Writer)` will write Corresponding **Content-Type** to the response. Apparently it occurs after setting the status code (after calling method `WriterHeader`). According to the comment on method `ResponseWriter.Header()`, changing the header map after a call to `WriteHeader` (or `Write`) has no effect unless the modified headers are trailers. But setting Content-Type works in Gin.

```
func writeContentType(w http.ResponseWriter, value []string) {
    header := w.Header()
    if val := header["Content-Type"]; len(val) == 0 {
        header["Content-Type"] = value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c.Writer` is a `gin.ResponseWriter` (probably the concrete type `gin.responseWriter`), not an `http.ResponseWriter`. While it implements the same interface, it *doesn't* do it in an identical way. Gin's `WriteHeader` *doesn't* send the headers immediately; it just stores the `code` internally in the writer, and `WriteHeaderNow` calls the "real" `WriteHeader` from `net/http` with the stored code.

`WriteHeaderNow` is called directly by the function you quoted in the case where there's no body; if there is a body, then `WriteHeaderNow` gets called on the first `Write` to the body.